# sudo snap install conjure-up --classic fails with configuring hook

Tags: snap, lxd, kubernetes

I am trying to run kubernetes on lxd following the instructions taken from https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/ubuntu/local/. However, I get following error message:

```
$ sudo snap install conjure-up --classic
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Run configure hook of "conjure-up" snap if present (run hook "configure": / has 'other' write 40777)
```

Does anyone know the reason for this error and how to fix it?

Thanks a lot.

P.S.: I tried installing conjure via apt, but it tells me that that has been moved to snap.